# Spring Selenium error creating RemoteWebDriver (io.opentelemetry)

Tags: java, spring, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Spring Selenium framework and when trying to instantiate RemoteWebDriver, i'm getting the same error even with the simplest code.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'preconditionSteps': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'driver'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'remoteChromeDriver' defined in class path resource [com/osmolka/fw/config/RemoteWebDriverConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver]: Factory method 'remoteChromeDriver' threw exception; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: io.opentelemetry.sdk.autoconfigure.spi.traces.SdkTracerProviderConfigurer: org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.opentelemetry.SeleniumSpanExporter not a subtype

I need to run tests on AWS, so used this:

```
@ThreadScopeBean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public WebDriver remoteChromeDriver() {
    String myProjectARN = "<project-arn>";
    DeviceFarmClient client  = DeviceFarmClient.builder().region(Region.US_WEST_2).build();
    CreateTestGridUrlRequest request = CreateTestGridUrlRequest.builder()
            .expiresInSeconds(300)
            .projectArn(myProjectARN)
            .build();
    CreateTestGridUrlResponse response = client.createTestGridUrl(request);
    URL testGridUrl = null;
    try {
        testGridUrl = new URL(response.url());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "chrome");
    capabilities.setCapability("browserVersion", "latest");
    capabilities.setCapability("platform", "windows");

    RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(testGridUrl, capabilities);

    return driver;
}
```

Absolute same peace of code with same env. variables works on a project created from scratch, but without Spring. but actually does not matter what code to write as long as it compiles. Same error appears even for something like that:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setCapability("browserVersion", "103");
chromeOptions.setCapability("platformName", "Windows 10");
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://www.google.com"), chromeOptions);
```

So this eeror thrown every time when calling new RemoteWebDriver. Struggling with this for few days already...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to disable opentelemetry by using another constructor:
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(testGridUrl, capabilities, false);